# How can I make an HTML element rotate with CSS inline only, or even without CSS at all?

Tags: html, css

I have a task that requires to rotate a logo with only inline CSS, and without JS at all.

I tried to look forward into defining an animation in the `style` attribute but couldn't find a thing.

Comment: What do you mean withoit css but only inline style? Please read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: @Sfili_81. When it comes to using CSS, I am allowed to use only inline styling. Sorry, my mistake, but I am in a hurry!

Comment: You can not set up animations using _only_ inline styling, because you can not define the @keyframes rules inline.

Comment: @AlexandruPeter you must use css in page, only inline you can't

Comment: as already wrote in previous comments you can't "animate" with inlline only. If you want to put a logo (what is your logo? bitmap image? svg?...) with an fixed angle, you can inline

Comment: You can write CSS in an SVG file and do the rotation there so you don't have to write inline CSS, in-file CSS, or JS.

Answer (score 1):

You can't define animation inline. The animation is not declared in the element, it's only called upon it.

However If you only want to rotate (not animate), you can do this with css `transform` property.

Here is an example:

```html
<div style="transform: rotate(45deg)">
  <img src="https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/so/logo-stackoverflow.svg" alt="logo"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference) {
  .logo {
    animation: logo-spin infinite 20s linear;
  }
}

@keyframes logo-spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

please try this code